# Google Cloud Vision Document OCR - keep layout in the resulted text

Tags: ocr, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

I use Google Cloud Vision Document OCR API. The resulted text that is returned by `com.google.cloud.vision.v1.AnnotateImageResponse.getFullTextAnnotation().getText()` is a little bit messy and lose the text formatting presented on the original image.

Is there with Google Cloud Vision Document OCR API a way to keep the layout(formatting) in the resulted text?

Answer (score 0):

At this point of time(1/24/2018), there is no Rich Text Output from the Google Vision OCR. You can only differentiate the lines. There is other way around which is pretty time consuming using the *bounding boxes*, I don't think that's the solution you are looking for.